# How to construct lambda payload to invoke another lambda?

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda proxy function (A) working along with API Gateway that I use to store some data in a remote database. I have another lambda function (B) that processes some data and I wish to reuse A to save data in the database.

I am therefore invoking A from B with a payload. I am able to invoke from B only if I convert this payload from a dictionary to a json it seems. Function A works fine when working along with API Gateway but when I invoke it from B I get an error when I do:

```
body = json.loads(event['body']) # [ERROR] TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

Let's say this is the code I use in B to invoke A:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

lambda_payload = {
        'headers': {},
        'response': False,
        'queryStringParameters': {},
        'body': { 'user_id' : 2, 'payload' : {'name': "James", 'age': 35}}
    }
    
lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='A', 
                     InvocationType='RequestResponse',
                     Payload=json.dumps(lambda_payload))
```

And the following is function A:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):   
    
    body = json.loads(event['body'])
...
```

I would prefer not having to change A but do the changes in B if possible. But if there is no other way I will handle it in A of course. How could I solve this? I am confused with the event type.

Comment: Use of `lambda` can be confusing for Python developers because it's a Python keyword.
Example : `lambda x: x+1`.
The error means that `json.loads()` expects a string but you provided a dict.
Maybe you can try `body = event['body']`

Comment: Why would it be a dict in A if the payload I send to A from B is json format by doing `Payload=json.dumps(lambda_payload)`?

Answer (score 0):

If `Payload` contains the data to be shared from function `A` to function `B`.

In `A` at the time you invoke function `B` : it's a string - result of the `json.dumps()` function.

So in `B` when you process `Payload` - as it is a string - **you can't access to a `body` index as it were a dict**.

I'm afraid you'll have to do minor changes on `A` and `B` as the interface between both ends has to be modified.

You can do the following.

In `B` send the body part as a string :

```py
lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='A', 
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    Payload=json.dumps(lambda_payload["body"]))
```

In `A` just use the string.

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # body = event
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to modify function A but only function B I did this before invoking:

````
lambda_payload['body'] = json.dumps(lambda_payload['body'])

lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='A', 
                         InvocationType='RequestResponse',
                         Payload=json.dumps(lambda_payload))
```
````